# What is file name extension .done?

Tags: file, file-extension

What is the file name extension ".done"?

How to handle the files with this extension? For example `filename.log.gz.done` is file name, can we just remove the `done` extension and use it?

What is the use of this file extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

".done" is just a marker that signifies that the file is ready for consumption.

So yes, get rid of the done extension and use it.

More details can be found here: http://www.davsclaus.com/2010/12/camel-26-using-done-files-with-fileftp.html

Answer (score 1):

> The ".done" file extension may be appended onto any type of file, such as a .TXT or .LOG file, and may be found on an FTP server where multiple have access to the file. The DONE file helps prevents a user from accessing a file that is not meant to be accessed. The ".done" extension should be removed in order to open the actual file.

[This takes you to the source](https://fileinfo.com/extension/done) from which I'm quoting my answer from. You will see a clear explanation of .done file extension and it's also a great reference for any other file extensions that you might need information about